# Can a valid GeoJSON Polygon represent an island in a lake in an island?

Tags: geojson

I was a bit puzzled to find the GeoJSON

```json
{
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [-0.8, -0.8],
      [ 0.8, -0.8],
      [ 0.8,  0.8],
      [-0.8,  0.8],
      [-0.8, -0.8]
    ],
    [
      [-0.6, -0.6],
      [-0.6,  0.6],
      [ 0.6,  0.6],
      [ 0.6, -0.6],
      [-0.6, -0.6]
    ],
    [
      [-0.4, -0.4],
      [ 0.4, -0.4],
      [ 0.4,  0.4],
      [-0.4,  0.4],
      [-0.4, -0.4]
    ]
  ]
}
```

an "island in a lake in an island" if you will, rejected by [one online validator](https://geojsonlint.com/), but accepted by [another](https://www.itb.ec.europa.eu/json/geojson/upload).

Looking again at RFC7846

> For Polygons with more than one of these rings, the first MUST be
> the exterior ring, and any others MUST be interior rings.  The
> exterior ring bounds the surface, and the interior rings (if
> present) bound holes within the surface.

it looks to me that the first validator was correct, the final ring does not bound a hole in the surface defined by the first ring, so is invalid.  So am I right in thinking that a valid GeoJSON Polygon cannot represent an island in a lake in an island? (So one would need to use a MultiPolygon to represent it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, the inner rings are holes in the exterior ring so cannot have an island in a lake where an inner ring is not a hole.

[image: Island in a lake as a multipolygon geometry]

A valid representation of an island would be a MultiPolygon where the first polygon is the larger polygon with a hole that forms the lake and the second polygon is the smaller polygon inside the first which is the island.

Here is the GeoJSON:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          [-0.8, -0.8],
          [ 0.8, -0.8],
          [ 0.8,  0.8],
          [-0.8,  0.8],
          [-0.8, -0.8]
        ],
        [
          [-0.6, -0.6],
          [-0.6,  0.6],
          [ 0.6,  0.6],
          [ 0.6, -0.6],
          [-0.6, -0.6]
        ]       
      ], [
        [
          [-0.4, -0.4],
          [ 0.4, -0.4],
          [ 0.4,  0.4],
          [-0.4,  0.4],
          [-0.4, -0.4]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be the problem I am having with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75383656/turf-mask-returns-polygon-without-hole-in-it Do you have an idea how I could achieve this?