# Turf Mask returns Polygon without hole in it

Tags: javascript, polygon, geojson, turfjs

I am getting some weird result with [turf.mask()](https://turfjs.org/docs/#mask).

This is the `polygon` I am trying to run the `mask()` function with: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Stophface/50155878441205412001247878f58b63/raw/324021868304f96c795e7d8cd18ec2c6f45ee842/polygon.geojson

[image: Raw data]

According to the [docs](https://turfjs.org/docs/#mask), if the mask is undefined, the world extent is used. The result of `turf.mask(polygon, undefined)` is this

[image: Result of mask]

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Stophface/50155878441205412001247878f58b63/raw/5e71fc1c4e4d6815cfa22e15eb1bf10c9208231f/mask_result.geojson

So it is filling the interior ring
Why is it doing that?

Comment: Looks like turf are discarding the "island" for the sake of validity, but running that file through a validator, I still get "Line 7: Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule".  https://geojsonlint.com/  Probably best to raise and issue with the turf people ...

Comment: @jjg Yeah I went there already, no response. Can you think of a way how to mask that step by step, in order to keep the inner hole?

Comment: Some simple implementions of GeoJSON ignore inner rings in polygons and just deal with the exterior ring. You could break up the polygon into sub-polygons so there are no inner polygons. Can do this directly in code or using QGIS with geo operations on the polygons.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I must do it in JavaScript because it is an Application and it must be complaiant with GeoJSON. I was thinking about breaking it up into sub-polygons, avoiding inner polygons. I assume there is no "out-of-the-box" function for this?

Comment: Relatively easy to do in python using shapely. Not sure what support you can get in JavaScript libs but you can look around.

Comment: @CodeMonkey could you pin point me how to do it in shapely?

Comment: @four-eyes : checked and shapely performs a geom difference from a polygon with another geometry creating a polygon with inner holes rather than calculating coords of a polygon w/o inner rings :-(